# Excel: if A1 equals anything in column B, change to corresponding value in column C

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an uncleaned data set in excel. One of the columns is a list of place names but poorly spelled and inaccurately grouped.

I have extracted all the unique values possible and manually went and looked up and typed out what I would like them to be. So now I have two tabs: Tab One is the original data and Tab Two has all unique values from the original data in Column A, all the correct values corresponding to each incorrect value in Column B, additional information in columns C and D.

I need to find a way to search Column A in Tab One and if the value matches ANY value in Column A in Tab Two, to replace it with the corresponding value in Column B in Tab Two.

Any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: VLOOKUP() and a helper column should help with your problem, but as DavidPostill said, please provide some sample data and your expected results for better tips.

Comment: Please share the formula you have applied on the sheet.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that your sheets name are TabOne and TabTwo. TabTwo has 99 items form A2 to B100.

So, start from TabOne!E2 and type:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TabTwo!$B$2:$B$100,MATCH(A2,TabTwo!$A$2:$A$100,0)),B2)
```

Copy this all the way down. If there is a match, formula returns the value on TabTwo; if not it gets value from column B.

After you are sure, you can copy formula cells and **paste them as values** on TabOne's column B.

Note: I used IFEEROR because MATCH returns #N/A! if there isn't a match.

Comment: This answer is close to being useful.  You're confused about which columns are on which Tabs.  Tab 2 has information in Columns A:D.  OP has only said that Tab 1 has data in Column A.  If a match is not found, it would be better to return a message rather than whatever is in Column B of Tab 1, which is unknown at this point.